# Problem with trainable variable while transforming Tensorflow network to Keras version

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, reinforcement-learning

I want to rewrite a network in DDPG as follows using Keras, and I think what this code does is put state and action into a Dense layer together using Relu, then connect it with a Dense without activation function

```
    def _build_c(self, s, a, scope, trainable):
    with tf.variable_scope(scope):
        n_l1 = 30
        w1_s = tf.get_variable('w1_s', [self.s_dim, n_l1], trainable=trainable)
        w1_a = tf.get_variable('w1_a', [self.a_dim, n_l1], trainable=trainable)
        b1 = tf.get_variable('b1', [1, n_l1], trainable=trainable)
        net = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(s, w1_s) + tf.matmul(a, w1_a) + b1)
        return tf.layers.dense(net, 1, trainable=trainable)
```

The Keras version network I rewrite is as follows, but the performance is different from the original Tensorflow version, I wonder if I misunderstand the original code on the operation of trainable variable, and cannot just concatenate state and action.

```
    def create_critic_network(self, state_size,action_dim):
        print("Now we build the model")
        S = Input(shape=[state_size,])
        A = Input(shape=[action_dim,],name='action2')
        h0 = Concatenate()([S, A])
        h1 = Dense(HIDDEN_UNITS, activation='relu')(h0)
        V = Dense(action_dim)(h1)
        model = Model(input=[S,A],output=V)
        adam = Adam(lr=self.LEARNING_RATE)
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=adam)
        return model, A, S
```

Comment: `tf.matmul(s, w1_s) + tf.matmul(a, w1_a)` adds up the two tensors.

`Concatenate()([S, A])` combines the two as separate variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but how can I realize  `tf.matmul(s, w1_s) + tf.matmul(a, w1_a)` in Keras? I wonder if there are some similar functions to create trainable variables like `tf.get_variable` in Keras, or I can create the Keras network in another way?

Comment: You can use [Add layer](https://keras.io/api/layers/merging_layers/add/) to add two tensors.  Before that, you need to pass each input (`s` and `a`) to a separate `Dense` layer to implement the `tf.matmul` part.  To be more precise, you should set one of the `Dense` with `use_bias=False` to avoid redundancy.

Comment: oh I get it! Thank you very much!